# AJAX Form with CBV Django yileds Form_Invalid Response but still posts to DB

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

Basically, I have a simple form that only has one field, which requires a string of < 200 chars. The form is submitted via an AJAX request and the response should be to stay on the same page("drug_new") and return a success or a fail with details about what was committed to the DB.

What actually happens is:

> POST http://localhost:8000/drug/new/ 400 (Bad Request)

And the server log shows the following:

```
[18/Jul/2017 12:53:35] "GET /drug/new/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3909
invalid loop
[18/Jul/2017 12:53:37] "POST /drug/new/ HTTP/1.1" 400 37
[18/Jul/2017 12:53:37] "POST /drug/new/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0
[18/Jul/2017 12:53:38] "GET /drug/new/ HTTP/1.1" 200 3909
```

Somehow the data also gets posted at the DB level, so what gives?? I am thinking it might have something to do with including the csrftokenmiddleware in the data section of the ajax request, however when I try to exclude it, it results in an error 500. I know that I could just use a function based view to validate the form data, however I don't want to have a CBV and a function for the same view. There has to be a way to get the CBV to work with an ajax request. Thanks in advance! :D

Here are the related files:

**models.py**

```
class Drug(models.Model):
    #drug_barcode = models.ForeignKey('expirations.Barcode', related_nam='barcodes')
    name = models.CharField(max_length= 200)

    # def get_absolute_url(self):
    #     return reverse('drug_list')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    def early_exp(self):
        return self.expiration_dates.all().aggregate(Min('expirationDate')).values()[0]
```

**forms.py**

```
class DrugForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Drug
        fields = ('name',)
```

**views.py**

```
class AjaxableResponseMixin(object):
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_valid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            print('valid loop')
            data = {
                'pk': self.object.pk,
                }
            return JsonResponse(data)
        else:
            return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        response = super(AjaxableResponseMixin, self).form_invalid(form)
        if self.request.is_ajax():
            print('invalid loop')
            return JsonResponse(form.errors, status=400)
        else:
            return response

class CreateDrugView(AjaxableResponseMixin, CreateView):
    redirect_field_name = reverse_lazy('drug_list')
    form_class = DrugForm

    model = Drug

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('drug_new')
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from . import views as exp_view

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^$', exp_view.home, name = 'home'),
    url(r'^$', exp_view.DrugListView.as_view() , name = 'drug_list'),
    url(r'^list/$', exp_view.DrugExpListView.as_view() , name = 'drug_exp_list'),
    url(r'^drug/new/$',exp_view.CreateDrugView.as_view(), name = 'drug_new'),
]
```

**drug_form.html**

```
{% block content %}
<div class = "container">
    <h1>New Drug</h1>

    <form id="drug_form_id" method="POST" class="post-form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button id = "submit_drug" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
{% block javascript %}
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var frm = $("#drug_form_id")
    frm.submit(function () {
      console.log(frm.val());
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: {'form':frm.serialize() , 'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
      })
    });
})
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to serialize the form data for the ajax data. i.e.

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    data: $('#yourForm').serialize(); // Or $(this).serialize() if inside a .submit() function
});
```

Comment: still get the same error: `POST http://localhost:8000/drug/new/ 400 (Bad Request)` and the same thing gets posted at the serverside console(invalid loop arg) triggered at the form_invalid portion.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I should have looked closer. For the data do `$.ajax({data: $(this).serialize()});` I updated my answer to try to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Some mods were needed, but thanks to Cory I was able to find a way to make it work using the following function call:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var frm = $("#drug_form_id")
    frm.submit(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(frm.serialize());
      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url: "{% url 'drug_new' %}",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data){
          console.log(data);
        }
      })
    });
})
```